# Error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

una app me lanza el error java.lang.NullPointerException pero no se que parte del código es la que funciona mal, agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar, este es el código

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ImagePagerAdapter() {

        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mAllImages.length;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);
        assert imageLayout != null;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        if(mAllImages[position].endsWith(".gif")) {
           // spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Glide.with(ActivitySlideImage.this).load(Config.SERVER_URL + "/upload/" +
                    mAllImages[position])
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            resource.start();
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(imageView);

        }else {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Config.SERVER_URL + "/upload/" +
                    mAllImages[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail).into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {


                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivitySlideImage.this, "Error al cargar imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }



        container.addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

El error es este:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.solodroid.materialwallpaper.activities.ActivitySlideImage$ImagePagerAdapter$1.onException(ActivitySlideImage.java:501)
at com.solodroid.materialwallpaper.activities.ActivitySlideImage$ImagePagerAdapter$1.onException(ActivitySlideImage.java:497)
at com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest.onException(GenericRequest.java:547)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.handleExceptionOnMainThread(EngineJob.java:183)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.access$200(EngineJob.java:22)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$MainThreadCallback.handleMessage(EngineJob.java:204)
```

Comment: Hugo, En tu LogCat busca la sección "Caused by..." y agregala por favor. Tienes una clase llamada ActivitySlideImage? Agregala 

Comment: Si tengo una clase llamada ActivitySlideImage, vale lo probaré, gracias.

Comment: Pero que probaras Hugo, el problema esta seguramente en esta clase, podrías agregarla.

Comment: vale es que no sabia muy bien a que te referias, la clase ActivitySlideImage es la que contiene el código que he pasado, aunque solo es una parte de código, pero es donde está el error.

Comment: No he puesto el error del LogCat porque en android studio no sale el problema, solo lo muestra en la Play Store.